# What does the phrase "hold up" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase "held up" mean in the following transcript?

> This campaign season, there's been plenty of name calling and lots of accusations. David Clementson, a PhD candidate at The Ohio State University, has been keeping tabs. "I mean there was one debate whereRubio and Cruz were just all over Trump, accusing him of dodging questions."
>
> Clementson wanted to see if claims of question dodging actually **held up**, historically—not necessarily in the unique case of Trump. So Clementson analyzed the transcripts of 14 presidential debates, from 1996 to 2012. Overall, he found 51 accusations of question dodging—26 by Dems, 25 by Republicans.

Comment: A claim is said to "*held up*" when it still remains valid after scrutiny and attempts to disprove it in the same way a wall can be said to have "held up" after it has successfully withstood attempts to tear it down or breach it.

Comment: *Hold up* is an interesting phrase/idiom, in that it has several different meanings.  Physically, someone can *hold up* a banner, a train might *hold up* traffic, a masked bandit may instigate a *holdup*, robbing a bank, and, as in this case, some physical object or metaphorical concept may *hold up*, successfully resisting the pressures of the physical world or intellectual examination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a structure *held up* in a storm or over time, then it was constructed well.  In the same way, if a claim *held up*, then it is accurate and solid.

Answer (score 2):

**hold** (definition 3.3 from [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hold?q=held+up#hold__24))

> (Of an argument or theory) be logical, consistent, or convincing:
>   *their views still seem to **hold up** extremely well*
>   *If your argument **holds**, why are you bothering to say anything here?*
>   *And if something travels faster than light Einstein's Theory doesn't **hold**.*
>   *She shows that the upbeat view doesn't **hold up** in the face of a careful examination of the numbers.*

The statement in question is:

> Clementson wanted to see if claims of question dodging actually **held up**, historically … . So Clementson analyzed the transcripts of 14 presidential debates, from 1996 to 2012. Overall, he found 51 accusations of question dodging—26 by Dems, 25 by Republicans.

Clementson analyzed the transcripts in order to ascertain whether the "claims of question dodging" were consistent / convincing … .

Comment: This is general reference, as your answer shows.